# Downgrade from Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_292

Tags: java, java-8

Good morning, I have an application that works only with Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_292, however we are in the Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_312 version. How can I install it?

Comment: IMHO you are solving the wrong problem. You should not ask how to install an old version of the JDK with known security problems and bugs, you should fix the application so that it works with the OpenJDK 1.8.0_312 version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go here: https://adoptium.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk8
2. download package
3. extract package
4. try calling it direclty (`/new/path/jdk8/bin/java -version`). This should now differ from calling the default java (`java -version`)
5. instead of calling the first java the systems finds (like `java -Xmx500G -jar  yourApp.jar`), run your app via direct java path call: `/new/path/jdk8/bin/java -Xmx500G -jar  yourApp.jar`
6. For Windows you can create .bat files, for linux you can create runnable bash scripts etc.

Oh, and a little side note: if that app is really only running under a certain revision version of java, it's probably really bad software...